# how can i filter whole line which contains a specific string

Tags: ant

i have the following Ant script for reading revisionlog.txt file line by line and printing all the line.

```
<target name="line_by_line">
   <loadfile property="file" srcfile="revisionlog.txt"/>
   <for param="line" list="${file}" delimiter="${line.separator}">
      <sequential>
         <echo>@{line}</echo>       
     </sequential>
   </for>
</target>
```

but here i want to print those line only which contains `Comments:` string.
how can i do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may use `loadfile` combined with a filterchain, f.e. :

```
<loadfile property="yourline" srcfile="revisionlog.txt">
  <filterchain>
    <linecontains>
      <contains value="Comments:"></contains>
    </linecontains>
  </filterchain>
</loadfile>

<echo>$${yourline} = ${line.separator}${yourline}</echo>
```

if you need more control, use `<linecontainsregexp>`
see Ant manual for [FilterChains and FilterReaders](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#linecontainsregexp)